# Infer one generic parameter, specify the other(s)

Tags: swift, generics, type-inference

I have a `struct` that is generic in two parameters, `Flag` and `DataType`:

```
struct FlagMapper<Flag, DataType> {

    let data: DataType

    init(_ data: DataType) {
        self.data = data
    }
}
```

The `DataType` could be inferred from the parameter `data` in the initializer. So I would like to write

```
let mapper = FlagMapper<MyFlag>(data)
```

when I create a new `FlagMapper`. In other words: I only want to specify the generic parameter that cannot be inferred and implicitly infer the other one.

Is there a way to accomplish this in *Swift*?

Or do I always have to specify both generic parameters?

```
let mapper = FlagMapper<MyFlag, MyDataType>(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best Swift has to offer is to pass a metatype.

```swift
struct FlagMapper<Flag, Data> {
  let data: Data

  init(_: Flag.Type, _ data: Data) {
    self.data = data
  }
}
```

```swift
let mapper = FlagMapper(MyFlag.self, data)
```

Comment: Okay, so it's either _specify both generic parameters_ or _none and have them both inferred_, I assume? The latter approach avoids specifying redundant information at least and is a little more concise than my original approach `FlagMapper<MyFlag, MyDataType>(data)`.

Comment: Right. Is there another language that offers this feature? How does it scale with more placeholders?

Comment: Not that I know of. It was my urge for perfection (and to eliminate redundancy) that made me ask this question. ;) After all, omitting all generic parameters is possible _Swift_ when all of them can be inferred and this "all or nothing" thing doesn't seem very elegant to me. But as generic parameters have no labels, I do see the problem for the compiler, of course...

Answer (score 2):

You have to let the compiler know how to build your `FlagMapper<Flag, DataType>` :

```
 let mapper = FlagMapper<MyFlag>(data)
```

is illegal since `FlagMapper` takes two generic parameters and you will probably get something like :

> Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project

and since the `FlagMapper` initializer is :

```
init(_ data: DataType)
```

with:

```
 let mapper = FlagMapper(data)
```

it only knows that `DataType` is the type of `data` but it has no clue about what `Flag` is.

So **yes** you need both generic parameters:

```
let mapper = FlagMapper<MyFlag, MyDataType>(data)
```

or

```
let mapperFlagMapper: FlagMapper<MyFlag, MyDataType> = FlagMapper(data)
```

or the variant:

```
let mapperFlagMapper: FlagMapper<MyFlag, MyDataType> = .init(data)
```

or even:

```
struct FlagMapper<Flag, DataType> {

    let data: DataType

    init(_ data: DataType, flagType: Flag.Type) {
        self.data = data
    }
}
let mapperFlagMapper: FlagMapper = .init(data, flagType: MyDataType.self)
```

Comment: The compiler _does_ have (or at least _could_ have) a clue what `Flag` is in your first line of code: It's the type `MyFlag` which we specify as a generic parameter. The other generic type `DataType` could be inferred from the `data` parameter. But from both your answer _I infer_ that the Swift compiler does not have this capability, so I guess the answer is pretty much: "Yes, I do have to specify both generic parameter – or make them both inferable from the initializer's parameters." The mixed approach is not possible.

Comment: That's what I meant by "So yes you need both generic parameters" ;) And yes it _could_ have a clue but it makes sense to me that it treat `FlagMapper<MyFlag>` as a syntax error (And therefore considers that it doesn't have enough to infer types)